# Order of files matched by a glob

Tags: linux, bash, shell, posix, globbing

Suppose I have the following files in a folder

```
1.txt
2.txt
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

If I match those files by a glob in order to process them, e.g.

```
for f in *;do echo $f;done
```

then `Bash` will match them - according to the man page - in an alphabetical order.

Is there, however, a POSIX standard that defines the matching order of globs? This way I could rely on a certain matching order in any shell, as long as it is POSIX conform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, ordering is required by POSIX.  From the [POSIX Spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_03):

> If the pattern matches any existing filenames or pathnames, the pattern shall be replaced with those filenames and pathnames, **sorted according to the collating sequence in effect in the current locale.** [Emphasis added]

To be assured of consistent results, one should specify a locale.  For programming, the setting `LC_COLLATE=C` is a common choice.

Comment: LC_ALL=C is not a very good choice though as it'll force everything else to ASCII mode. If all you want is collation order, set LC_COLLATE instead.

Comment: @grawity Yes, COLLATE is better.  Answer updated.